# Sklearn output is missing values after decimal

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I am using linearRegression to predict the values.  I am building user login prediction system and this are the login hours of each of the users.

My Dataset contains following values

```
login_hour Login_minute Login_second Login_day
11              20          30          2
11              21          45          2
11              45          10          2
```

There are thousands such values and I am trying to predict on that. i am using Sklearn library to do the prediction but my output values contains floating number with nothing after decimal. Also some of the numbers are negative even though there is no negative number in the dataset.

Below is my code

```
model = LinearRegression()
try:
    for users in user_list:
        data = df.loc[df['user_list'] == users, 'login_hour':'login_day']

        X_train, X_test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.5, random_state=int(time.time()))
        model.fit(X_train, X_test)
        if not df.loc[df['user_list'] == users].empty:
            X_predict = df.loc[df['user_list'] == users, 'login_hour':'login_day']
            print(users)
            print(model.predict(X_predict))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Below is the output.

```
User1
[[19.20795654 30.81796908 -1.17348934  4.        ]
 [19.20795654 30.81796908 -1.17348934  4.        ]
 [19.20795654 30.81796908 -1.17348934  4.        ]
 [19.24304221 38.74216465 35.94425407  4.        ]
 [19.29593815 36.93326369 40.6377267   4.        ]
 [18.88357989 53.14036774 11.89626968  4.        ]
 [18.88357989 53.14036774 11.89626968  4.        ]
 [19.29593815 36.93326369 40.6377267   4.        ]
 [19.29593815 36.93326369 40.6377267   4.        ]
 [18.88357989 53.14036774 11.89626968  4.        ]
 [19.43300738 28.03476807 37.10549659  4.        ]
 [19.43300738 28.03476807 37.10549659  4.        ]
 [19.43300738 28.03476807 37.10549659  4.        ]
 [19.         50.         51.          4.        ]
 [19.         50.         51.          4.        ]
 [19.         50.         51.          4.        ]]
User2
[[ 1.96245603e+01  8.73215646e+00  5.32679614e+00  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.96245603e+01  8.73215646e+00  5.32679614e+00  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.90995539e+01  3.32999402e+01  2.32454303e+01  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.90995539e+01  3.32999402e+01  2.32454303e+01  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 2.05057605e+01 -2.92241595e+01 -1.76151096e+01  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.97164859e+01  1.09897454e+01  1.64568207e+01  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.87643468e+01  3.99670330e+01  1.50683761e+01  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.88341735e+01  3.99791100e+01  1.98189050e+01  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.91961218e+01  3.78000218e+01  3.95673183e+01  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.91006661e+01  4.22668915e+01  4.28252518e+01  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.82946119e+01  7.81641824e+01  9.76385715e+01  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 2.00000000e+01 -4.54747351e-13  4.30000000e+01  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 2.00000000e+01 -4.54747351e-13  4.30000000e+01  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 2.00000000e+01 -4.54747351e-13  4.30000000e+01  4.00000000e+00]]
```

**Question**

You can see values like `4.` and `50.`, why are they missing values after the decimal and how can i get them to `4.0` or something. Also is the possible to restrict output to just 2 places of decimal or even zero places of decimal?

Also some of my output values are negative like `-4.54747351e-13`. I don't have any negative values in dataset but my output has. Can anyone give me reason why?

Comment: What do you want to predict? Can you explain your training data (features `X`) and labels (`y`) please? Do you apply any preprocessing steps?

Comment: I am building user login prediction system and this are the login hours of each of the users. i have done all the preprocessing and all but the output is giving me issues.

Comment: So did you train for each user a model? And did you [evaluate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics) your models? Finally you can try to train a non-linear model because it could be more feasible?

Comment: Yes i did train the model and the output is the "Prediction time' when the user will login. I have posted my code so you can look into it.

Comment: @Samvid Kulkarni Linear regression tries to fit your `X` values each corresponding to a `y` value. Your case seems like a time series problem. When you train your model using `model.fit(X_train, X_test)` it will try to fit each value in `X_train` to its corresponding value in `X_test`. I don't think it will help you identify time patterns.

Comment: @panktijk I see. what do you suggest then? Should I use some other algorithm like LSTM?

Comment: @Samvid Kulkarni Yes, you can look at models that are sequential in nature (LSTM being one of them).